# Mixing data from mysql in the same table using - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my tblRecords from mysql.

```
ID ---- Name ---- Remark1 ---- Remark2
1       Dead        ok           -
1       Dead        -            ok
```

when i call the data from tblRecords i want to display the output like this

```
ID ---- Name ---- Remark1 ---- Remark2
1       Dead        ok           ok
```

Please help i'm just a newbie in programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the character `-` itself, then the query may look like the following:

```sql
SELECT r.ID, r.Name,
IF (r1.Remark1, r1.Remark1, r.Remark1) AS Remark1,
IF (r2.Remark2, r2.Remark2, r.Remark2) AS Remark2
FROM tblRecords r
LEFT JOIN tblRecords r1 ON r1.ID = r.ID AND r1.Remark1 != '-'
LEFT JOIN tblRecords r2 ON r2.ID = r.ID AND r2.Remark2 != '-'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Here we [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) the table (`r`) with itself 2 times:
 - collecting non-dashed `Remark1` from `r1`
 - collecting non-dashed `Remark2` from `r2`

You might use `MAX(Remark1)` and `MAX(Remark2)` as suggested in another answer, if you don't care if there comes something different from `'ok'`, something like `'looks ok'`, for example. Otherwise, you'll have to implement some logic. Somehow I think the logic of your app implies different statuses, or you can add some statuses in future.

Also, the query above is slow, even if there indexes created for every case in the database. And its' incredibly slow, if the indexes by the remark columns are absent.

Therefore, I recommend implementing the logic in PHP. This will simplify and speed up the query. Besides, the storage engine shouldn't do a lot of the app logic.

Let's assume `Db` is a database abstraction layer, which connects to the database, if necessary, `Db::query()` accepts an SQL string and returns [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. Then the code might look like the following

```
// You might want to add WHERE clause.
$r = Db::query("SELECT * FROM tblRecords");

$records = [];
$keys = ['Remark1', 'Remark2'];
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id = $row['ID'];

  if (! isset($records[$id])) {
    $records[$id] = $row;
    continue;
  }

  foreach ($keys as $k) {
    if ($row[$k] != '-' && $records[$id][$k] == '-') {
      $records[$id][$k] = $row[$k];
    }
  }
}

$r->free();
```

As your app will grow, the logic will become more complicated. Believe me, you'll be happy the logic is in PHP, and not in SQL.

Comment: Got it thanks it works..but i got an error in `USING(ID)` so i replace it with `ON r1.ID=r2.ID`.. Thanks again @Ruslan

Comment: @V.Prince, updated the answer

Comment: @V.Prince, updated again. Added practical recommendations from my own experience.

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac68/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblRecords
    (`ID` int, `Name` varchar(4), `Remark1` varchar(4), `Remark2` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO tblRecords
    (`ID`, `Name`, `Remark1`, `Remark2`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Dead', 'ok', '-'),
    (1, 'Dead', '-', 'ok')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ID,Name,max(Remark1) as Remark1 ,max(Remark2) as Remark2
from tblRecords
group by ID,Name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac68/2/0)**:

```
| ID | Name | Remark1 | Remark2 |
|----|------|---------|---------|
|  1 | Dead |      ok |      ok |
```